# How to get ChromeSafariBrowser to launch on flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Overview:  I include flutter_inappwebview: 4.0.0+4 in pubspec.yaml and import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart'; in main.dart.  When I press browser, nothing happens and inspection reveals no errors.  However terminal throws error the platform is not supported.   The brower is suppose to load the flutter page from the web.   Am I missing parameters.  I need to launch an html to run javascript to do a QR Code reading.

Getting the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem at Object.throw_ [as throw] (localhost:55661/dart_sdk.js:4334:11) at Function._operatingSystem (localhost:55661/dart_sdk.js:55065:17) at Function.get operatingSystem [as operatingSystem] (localhost:55661/dart_sdk.js:55111:27)
```

Source Code

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //await Permission.camera.request();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  MyChromeSafariBrowser browser =
      new MyChromeSafariBrowser(new MyInAppBrowser());

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  debugPrint('browser pressed');
                  await widget.browser.open(
                      url: "https://flutter.dev/",
                      options: ChromeSafariBrowserClassOptions(
                          android: AndroidChromeCustomTabsOptions(
                              addDefaultShareMenuItem: false,
                              packageName: "com.android.chrome"),
                          ios: IOSSafariOptions(barCollapsingEnabled: true)));
                },
                child: Text("Browser"))));
  }
}

class MyInAppBrowser extends InAppBrowser {
  @override
  Future onLoadStart(String url) async {
    print("\n\nStarted $url\n\n");
  }

  @override
  Future onLoadStop(String url) async {
    print("\n\nStopped $url\n\n");
  }

  @override
  void onLoadError(String url, int code, String message) {
    print("\n\nCan't load $url.. Error: $message\n\n");
  }

  @override
  void onExit() {
    print("\n\nBrowser closed!\n\n");
  }
}

class MyChromeSafariBrowser extends ChromeSafariBrowser {
  MyChromeSafariBrowser(browserFallback) : super(bFallback: browserFallback);

  @override
  void onOpened() {
    print("ChromeSafari browser opened");
  }

  @override
  void onLoaded() {
    print("ChromeSafari browser loaded");
  }

  @override
  void onClosed() {
    print("ChromeSafari browser closed");
  }
}
```

Comment: Additional information should be edited into the question. It should not be provided in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flutter_inappwebview` doesn't support Flutter web (look at the supported platforms [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)).

To run javascript in Flutter web, you have to use something like [JS interop](https://medium.com/@liewjuntung/use-javascript-in-flutter-web-a6eed3efb9a0) or create a plugin that supports web (I think this uses JS interop under the hood, but it is the recommended way so that you don't mix native code with a Flutter app).

Comment: I started writing a conversion of pdfjs to dart, so that's what gave me most of my experience with it. Then I found a tool to convert typescript to dart (https://github.com/dart-lang/js_facade_gen), and since typescript bindings were available, I used that and just modified it to fit my needs. Since then a package was released that used pdfjs but also had Android and iOS working, so I switched to that. You can take a look at their web implementation here: https://github.com/dart-lang/js_facade_gen

Comment: I need to run a qr reader javascript code from a chrome browser.  Will js_facade_gen work

Comment: If it needs a camera preview window, I would imagine that will be difficult, but it should at least give you a basis to work on. It's basically automation of JS interop, so you can modify it afterwards

Comment: Explain how I would use your code in Flutter and dart

Comment: I switched to angular 8 for the project with c# web api.  I write my code using visual studio code and ng build --prod the code and copy the dist to the wwwroot of the webapi and deploy it to the iis server.